# Running a specific set of methods of sub-classes without explicitly calling them

Tags: python, class-design

I'm implementing the following in Python: (code skeleton below)

```
    class Base(object):

        def __init__(self, run_ext):
        def common_method1(self, run_ext):
        def common_method2(self, run_ext):


        def run_all(self):
             """Run all the methods beginning with run*"""  

    class Ext1(Base):

        def run11(self):
        def run12(self):

        def notrelated11(self):


    class Ext2(Base):

        def run21(self):
        def run22(self):

        def notrelated21(self):


Ext1.run_all()  # should run all the *'run*'* methods in Ext1 and 
Ext2.run_all()  # should run all the *'run*'* methods in Ext2.
```

Objective:
Implementing run_all() in the base class that would run a specific set of methods from the sub-class when called.

Thoughts:
 - The vanilla way of doing it is by making explicit calls to the methods in the sub-classes and defining run_all in the parent class as an abstract method. 
 - A somewhat hacky way is setting an attribute (or identifying the methods to be run by their names).

I'm looking for any better alternative solutions..

- Also wanted to know if this problem fits in with any existing design pattern?

**Note:** The child classes may contain other methods than just run1, run2.. the not_related methods mentioned above.

Update: As pointed out by @mkriheli the base class wouldn't/shouldn't know about the child classes inheriting from it.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot self when calling the run methods (self.run1()...).

Comment: Well I guess run1() and run2() could be declared in the superclass and then overloaded, since they have the same name and appear in both children classes. Unless it's a coincidence (if it is, change their names as it might be confusing).

Comment: This is a bad design, a class should have no knowledge about those inheriting from it.

Comment: the sub-classes' methods would be different. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @mkriheli that's a nice point.

Comment: I prefer using decorators, as it is more clean and pythonic. But if you insist on that, maybe you may use self.__class__.__dict__ which will give you all the things from the class, amongst which you can find the functions.

Answer (score 2):

How about using decorators:

```
import inspect

def runnable(f):
  setattr(f, '__can_run__', True)
  return f

class Base:
  def run_all(self):
    for runner_name in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
      func = getattr(self, runner_name[0])
      if hasattr(func, '__can_run__'):
        if getattr(func, '__can_run__'):
          func()

class Child(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    self.incremental = 0

  @runnable
  def run1(self):
    self.incremental += 1
    print "running", self.incremental

  @runnable
  def run2(self):
    self.incremental += 1    
    print "running", self.incremental


c = Child()
c.run_all()
```

Output:

```
running 1
running 2
```

Please note that I do not recommend using `inspect` and what you are trying might be possible in a better way. `inspect` is a CPython implementation feature, and is not guaranteed to be present in other Python implementations. Do not do `Wrong Thing To Do`.

Comment: I'm using a CPython implementation and this is a nice way of getting the work done but I'm looking for a more simple/subtle solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of @Nandeep, a inspect-free alternative

```
class runnable(object):
  run_list = []
  @staticmethod
  def add(f):
    runnable.run_list.append(f)

class Base:
  def run_all(self):
    for runner_name in runnable.run_list:
      # Now you have all the functions


class Child(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    self.incremental = 0

  @runnable.add
  def run1(self):
    self.incremental += 1
    print "running", self.incremental
```

Comment: Will multiple children, which are adding 'runnables' to this static class, cause problems? Because they are all adding to the same `run_list`.